# how to decode qr code that contains base 64 png in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, qr-code, zxing

I have been trying to decode this QR code that has JSON data.

[image]

In online tools it's working example https://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/. It reads the data. I am trying programmatically.

Here is my code:

```
handleFileChange(event) {
    const {target} = event;
    const {files} = target;

    if (files && files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      //  reader.onloadstart = () => this.setState({loading: true});

      reader.onload = async event => {
        this.setState({
          data: event.target.result,
          loading: false
        });
       // const img = document.getElementById('img');
      console.log(event.target.result);
        let result;
        try {
          var qr = new QrCode();

// set the callback that receives the decoded content as the tasks is async
          qr.callback = function(decodedDATA){
            alert(decodedDATA);
          };

    // event.target.result is
 //data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...
          qr.decode(event.target.result);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        console.log(result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
  }
<input
              id="img"
              type="file"
              accept="image/*"
              onChange={this.handleFileChange}
            />
```

I have used this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-reader
It has bug that cannot read data more than certain characters hence i am getting error.

I have also tried to use zxing library but I am using server side rendering and getting error "window is undefined". There are lot of configurations need to be done in webpack but I am not aware of those.

I am looking for simple fix for this. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with this library qrcode-decoder.

In my code

```
import QrcodeDecoder from 'qrcode-decoder';

          const qr = new QrcodeDecoder();

         const result = await qr.decodeFromImage(event.target.result);
```

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. Throws an error while declaring the object for QrcodeDecoder.